# ASP mobile compatible websites

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have done a cms website by using aspx and  i need to make the website mobile compatible.
What are the techniques in asp to make a website mobile compatible?

Please help me.

Comment: You need to make different pages that fits on mobile. Google it: `making site for mobiles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing ASP.NET pages for mobile device browsers does not differ substantially from developing pages for desktop browsers. To help you create applications for mobile devices, ASP.NET provides a System.Web.Mobile namespace devoted specifically to mobile Web development.

Sample Code:

[**Mobile-enabled ASP.NET Web Forms / MVC application samples**](http://aspnetmobilesamples.codeplex.com/)

Refer this:

[ASP.NET Web Sites for Mobile Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178619%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Mobile Support in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mobile)

[jQuery Mobile Framework](http://jquerymobile.codeplex.com/)